# How much force applied to canal wall from that cargo ship given 220,000 tons and 12.8 knots?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision, estimation

In case you've been hiding under a rock, or are reading this in the future: "that cargo ship" is a huge story right now (3/26/2021). A brief summary: well basically a few days ago one of the world's largest cargo ships somehow managed to dig its bulbous bow into the east wall of the Suez canal. The back end of the ship is resting on the west end and no other ships can pass. I read 220,000 tons and 12.8 knots https://www.baltimoresun.com/news/nation-world/ct-aud-nw-cargo-ship-stuck-egypt-suez-canal-20210324-oytkblgh5ngihlwitcy7hdsnwi-story.html and thought it might make a fun little physics question. Another one I thought of is how much volume of water that much weight displaces...

Comment: half a cup of coffee later switchin on my physics brain a few things occur to me.. first of all force is mass times acceleration and it would actually be a matter of deceleration over the time that the ship came to a stop, or impulse I guess? Secondly Idk how much momentum the water would adsorb with the ship swinging around, or smacking into the other bank, but maybe make a simplifying asumption that the ship just ran perpendicular into only the east bank as looking at pics the west bank looks less affected?

Comment: I think we'd also need to know how long the collision took... :(

Comment: Right! Or alternatively per my answer if we know stopping distance

Comment: The amount of *energy* dissipated in the grounding can be calculated with no additional information.

Comment: Good thinking @G. Smith well... 12.8 knots = 6.6 m/s, and 220000 tons = 199580643 kg, so kinetic energy was .5mv^2=(199580643/2)*(6.6*6.6)=4,346,866,404.5 joules which is a little more than 1 ton of tnt. I wonder if there was any seismometers nearby.

Comment: @Bob D, I been staring at a few pics trying to guestimate that, but it's really hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can be determined what the stopping distance was for the ship, such as by a measurement of the depth of penetration of the ship into the canal wall, and can ignoring the resistance of the water to the ship movement, one can estimate the average impact force using the work energy theorem, which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or

$$F_{ave}d=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Where $F_{ave}$ is the average impact force, $d$ is the stopping distance of the ship, and $v$ is the ship velocity just prior to impact.

[image: what the ship and canal bank might look like under water]
if we use 50 meters as a guess we get 4,346,866,404.5 joules / 50m = 86,937,328 newtons

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the volume of water displaced...  Archimedes principle says that "a floating body displaces it's own weight of the liquid in which it floats".

So the cargo ship displaces 220,000 tons or 200,000,000 kg of water.  For a density of water of 1000kg per cubic metre that's 200,000 cubic metres of water displaced.

Apparently some other ships are detouring around the Cape of Good Hope, some detour!